# conda update failed with CondaValueError:MAlformed version string '~': invalid character(s)

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, failed-installation

I want to update conda with commands:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

but it failed, and show the following info:

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaValueError: Malformed version string '~': invalid character(s).
```

then I use the following commands,and don't solve the problem:

```
$ conda upgrade -n base -c defaults --override-channels conda
Solving environment: failed

InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7
```

how can I solve the problem?why it happends?